# Why is "Users" file size so big?

Tags: hard-drive

Why is "Users" file so huge? I am Migrating my Time Capsule's copy of my Air hard drive back to my Air with brand new Hard drive installed.

Answer (score 2):

The `/Users` folder is so big because that's where *all* the user data is stored. All the pictures, library files, movies, etc.